# jq array filter for nested array elements

Tags: jq

I am trying to add a new user in below json which matches group NP01-RW. i am able to do without NP01-RW but not able to select users under NP01-RW and return updated json.

```
{
  "id": 181,
  "guid": "c9b7dbde-63de-42cc-9840-1b4a06e13364",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "version": 17,
  "service": "Np-Hue",
  "name": "DATASCIENCE-CUROPT-RO",
  "policyType": 0,
  "policyPriority": 0,
  "isAuditEnabled": true,
  "resources": {
    "database": {
      "values": [
        "hive_cur_acct_1dev",
        "hive_cur_acct_1eng",
        "hive_cur_acct_1rwy",
        "hive_cur_acct_1stg",
        "hive_opt_acct_1dev",
        "hive_opt_acct_1eng",
        "hive_opt_acct_1stg",
        "hive_opt_acct_1rwy"
      ],
      "isExcludes": false,
      "isRecursive": false
    },
    "column": {
      "values": [
        "*"
      ],
      "isExcludes": false,
      "isRecursive": false
    },
    "table": {
      "values": [
        "*"
      ],
      "isExcludes": false,
      "isRecursive": false
    }
  },
  "policyItems": [
    {
      "accesses": [
        {
          "type": "select",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "update",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "create",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "drop",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "alter",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "index",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "lock",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "all",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "read",
          "isAllowed": true
        },
        {
          "type": "write",
          "isAllowed": true
        }
      ],
      "users": [
        "user1",
        "user2",
        "user3"
      ],
      "groups": [
        "NP01-RW"
      ],
      "conditions": [],
      "delegateAdmin": false
    },
    {
      "accesses": [
        {
          "type": "select",
          "isAllowed": true
        }
      ],
      "users": [
        "user1"
      ],
      "groups": [
        "NP01-RO"
      ],
      "conditions": [],
      "delegateAdmin": false
    }
  ],
  "denyPolicyItems": [],
  "allowExceptions": [],
  "denyExceptions": [],
  "dataMaskPolicyItems": [],
  "rowFilterPolicyItems": [],
  "options": {},
  "validitySchedules": [],
  "policyLabels": [
    "DATASCIENCE-CurOpt-RO_NP01"
  ]
}
```

below is what i have tried but it returns part of the JSON matching NP01-RW and not full JSON

jq --arg username "$sync_userName" '.policyItems[] | select(.groups[] | IN("NP01-RO")).users += [$username]' > ${sync_policyName}.json

Comment: Put parentheses around the whole LHS, i.e. `(.policyItems[] | select(.groups[] | IN("NP01-RO")).users) += [$username]`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jgjcCZvB_pe)

Comment: Thanks for this. This has worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator precedence in jq is not always intuitive. Your program is parsed as:

```
.policyItems[] | (select(.groups[] | IN("NP01-RO")).users += [$username])
```

Which first streams all policyItems and only then changes them, leaving you with policyItems only in the output.

You need to make sure that the stream selects the correct values, which you can then assign:

```
(.policyItems[] | select(.groups[] | IN("NP01-RO")).users) += [$username]
```

This will do the assignment, but still return the full input (`.`).